# Selective product installation in MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.6 Community Edition Installation installs the following folders, but I just want to install the server alone and don't need any connectors or excel or docs. How should I do a custom install to do what I need.

C:\Program Files\MySQL>dir

Volume in drive C has no label.

Volume Serial Number is 96FE-9B3F

Directory of C:\Program Files\MySQL

13-02-2013 PM 01:15  .

13-02-2013 PM 01:15  ..

13-02-2013 PM 01:14  Connector C++ 1.1.2

13-02-2013 PM 01:14  Connector J 5.1.23

13-02-2013 PM 01:15  Connector NET 6.6.5

13-02-2013 PM 01:14  Connector ODBC 5.2.4

13-02-2013 PM 01:15  MySQL Documentation 5.6.10

13-02-2013 PM 01:14  MySQL For Excel 1.1.0

13-02-2013 PM 12:05  MySQL Installer

13-02-2013 PM 01:14  MySQL Notifier 1.0.3

13-02-2013 PM 01:13  MySQL Server 5.6

13-02-2013 PM 01:21  MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.46

13-02-2013 PM 01:15  Samples and Examples 5.6.10

0 File(s) 0 bytes

13 Dir(s) 71,534,161,920 bytes free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Launch MySQL5.6 Installer
- At the *Setup Type* step, select **Custom** :
  [image: Setup Type]
  <sub>(source: [canardpc.com](http://tof.canardpc.com/view/59bffdc9-1022-4601-8750-97f8f21154a0.jpg))</sub>

change the installation path and/or the data path if you need to,

- At the next step, *Feature Selection*, just select what you need, **MySQL Server 5.6.10** in your case :
  [image: Feature Selection]
  <sub>(source: [canardpc.com](http://tof.canardpc.com/view/076e9e82-519e-4eae-b029-ea739deb09df.jpg))</sub>
- Complete the installation and the configuration of your MySQL Server as usually (many tutorials are available for this part)